How can I measure a 0-3.3V analog signal through an isolation barrier?
I am running into an issue where I have to be able to receive an analog DC voltage that will vary from 0-3.3VDC, but I need to be able to isolate the signal before I run it through an amplifier and a low pass filter, then process it. I've been trying to find solutions to achieve this for about a week now and haven't made much progress, finding a lot more solutions that won't work than anything. I did see a post where an answer that essentially avoid it if possible, even for newbies, but I am in a situation where I cannot.

This is a Q&A site. You need to ask an aswerable question. Which also means give enought details and background info what you are doing, from where the signal comes, what are the signal properties, and why it must be isolated.

OK, you say you want to process the signal, what kind of processing is it? Does it have a digital or analog output? Can it be moved on the other side of the isolation barrier? Basically, isolating analog is such a headache that the whole system is usually designed to avoid it. So the question must include a description of the whole system, so we can help you avoid isolating analog XD

can you use a VCO and an opto and a frequency counter to "blink" the voltage over a barrier w/o RC filter delays?

Low-power voltage-to-frequency converters exist for just this sort of application.

Your question is a bit vague, but usually, a problem like yours is solved by pre-processing your analog signal on the "unisolated" side, then using an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) there, and then sending the digital signal over the isolation barrier, which then can be an optocoupler, for example. There's (rather expensive) "isolation ADCs" that include the optical isolation and the digitization part, but they're not typically what you need for some "random" 3.3V range.
How you really implement that, which ADCs you need, or whether it might actually just be sufficient to "calibrate" the response of an optocoupler to an (amplified) analog input – impossible to tell without you going into much more detail on your system's needs.
So, strong recommendation to either enhance your question with a lot of details on how precisely you need to transport that voltage range, how quickly the signal can change (its bandwidth), how much noise is acceptable, how much power you can spend, what supply voltages you have on either side of the isolation barrier, against what exactly you need to isolate (ESD discharge? High voltage power line? …), where the reference potentials on both sides of the isolation barrier come from,…

This is the correct solution. Trying to send an analogue signal across opto isolation is just needlessly complicated and asking for trouble, why anyone suggesting such should be simply be ignored. Either pick an ADC with built-in isolation or use some SPI/I2C etc digital isolators.

I mean without doubts you'd be right in most cases, but if, for example, the analog signal was actually just something frequency-modulated with low bandwidth, the nonlinearity of things might be something that can be removed by means of means of filtering

The appropriate solution will depend on isolation voltage, CMRR, bandwidth and other requirements . Generally speaking, there are usually two requirements- to get power across the isolation barrier in one direction and to get the signal across in the other.
You can buy or make an isolated DC-DC converter for the first requirement. The second is usually fulfilled through some kind of analog-to-digital conversion, perhaps converting back to analog or not. There are purely analog means such as linear optocouplers but they are not so attractive these days. Another classic analog-ish method was to chop the DC signal and use a centre-tapped transformer for isolation.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Once the signal is in some kind of digital form (not necessarily binary- it could be PWM or something like that), it can be communicated over the barrier by optical, magnetic or differential capacitive means.
For example, for a low bandwidth application and low resolution/accuracy you could use a small MCU with on-chip ADC and send serial data via a fast logic-output optocoupler (or even a cheap slow optocoupler at low baud rates) and pick it up on the other side with another asynchronous serial port. You could stick an SPI or I2C ADC on the isolated side and just pass the communication signals (a simpler solution without programming but needs more signals to be transferred across the barrier). There are one-chip SPI and I2C isolators with multiple channels.
There are also compact one-chip solutions, developed primarily for the motor drive market, which combine both functions in one SOIC part, such as TI's AMC3330 which uses magnetic isolation for power and capacitive isolation for signal.

That kind of compact solution doesn't lend itself to the most efficient DC-DC converter so if power consumption is an issue, a separate DC-DC converter design might be better.

The way I've done this in the past is by using matched opto-couplers to send the signals over isolation. One problem is you get some gain distortion and the matching is something on the order of a few percent on gain for the good parts.

https://simple-circuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/analog-isolation-amplifier-hcnr201-circuit-optocoupler-hcnr200-scaled.webp
There are also some other ways to do this with IC's that are more accuracte: 
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso224.pdf?ts=1733196470869&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FISO224
But they cost more.
Another way is to just use an opto-coupler if you don't need linearity and accuracy.
The best way is to use an ADC and then to isolate the digital.

Chop it to make AC at a frequency greater then the low pass filter, (eg use a MOSFET H bridge)
Then pass it through a transformer for isolation.
Then envelope detect and low-pass the result.


You can drive optocoupler with PWM. The driving duty will be proportional to output voltage. But it has slow response because PWM needs to be filtered using RC.
Or use MCU to convert duty back to voltage.

Or…

Use two photo-diode optocoupler like HCNR200 (look datasheet). Take a feedback from one photo-diode (nonisolated) for driving the Led to reach desired output voltage and the second photo-diode (isolated) will be driven the same because both photo-diodes have the same properties.

